# How to update multiple fields in Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a databse **photos** in which the record of members are stored, it has **name**, **au_id ,**  **position ,**  **contact**  & **email** columns. There is secured panel where admin can change the details of the body members of the group. Complete form is shown again here with the values stored in database so if admin want to change any value he/she can do here and submit that form to update record. On successfull submission

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$au_id=$_POST['au_id'];
$position=$_POST['position'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

I am having trouble to update records of particular member. I have primary key **id** in my database. I am using:

```
$save="UPDATE photos SET name = '$name', au_id = '$au_id', position = '$position', cell = '$contact', email = '$email' WHERE id = '6' ";
$result=mysql_query($save);
```

and putted a check so that i can know that if query is successfully run or not,

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result))
{
   echo 'successfully updated';
}
else
{
  echo 'not updated';
}
```

it is giving successfully updated message but when i again go to check the records nothing is changed. how can i figure out this problem

Comment: `echo $save` and check if the query is correct.

Comment: `if(!$result) { echo mysql_error(); }` to check why $result returns false. Btw. you are always using id=6. Maybe the columns for id = 6 are already updated?

Comment: @Royal i have just pasted this row id to understand otherwise id will get change always depending on the edit button infront of every row in record preview page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$save="UPDATE photos SET name = '".$name."', au_id = '".$au_id."', position = '".$position."', cell = '".$contact."', email = '".$email."' WHERE id = '6' ";
$result=mysql_query($save);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$save="UPDATE photos SET name = '$name', au_id = '$au_id', position = '$position', cell = '$contact', email = '$email' WHERE id = '6' ";

if ($result=mysql_query($save))
{
   echo 'successfully updated';
}
else
{
  echo 'not updated';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
   use [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

```
$save="UPDATE photos SET name = '$name', au_id = '$au_id', position = '$position', cell = '$contact', email = '$email' WHERE id = '6' ";

$result=mysql_query($save);
$cnt=mysql_affected_rows();
if($cnt>0)
{
   echo 'successfully updated';
}
else
{
    echo 'not updated';
}
```

**mysql_ is deprecated function**

Answer (score 0):

mysql_num_rows should not be used for the SQL querys which does not return result set, like UPDATE, DELETE and so on.
mysql_query it self seems to work in some situations if mysql connection is properly done by mysql_connect and db is properly selected using mysql_select_db. So you should check whether the SELECT query works there.
However, if one of field contains "'", for example, your SQL query is collapsed. This is not just a problem which leads to error, but a vulnerability which allows "SQL injection". You should use placeholder. If placeholder can't be used for some reason, you must use mysql_real_escape_string to escape your fields.

Answer (score 0):

As you are mention in your question columns are :-

`name, au_id , position , contact & email`

two things I have catch in your code:-

1) You are mention `contact` column and your updating with `cell`.
 2) You have not declare `$contact` variable.

Please run query with correct column name and if id is not string then no need to use `id = '6'` you can use `id = 6`

Answer (score 0):

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, `mysql_query()` returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues)

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, `mysql_query()` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

So you get `true` or `false` on executing the query and obviously `mysql_num_rows(true)` makes no sense.